# how to rearrange the column order in ODI mapping

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

we want to rearrange the column order in ODI mapping.
So we can move the blob datatype column at end to avoid the error "ORA-24816: Expanded non LONG bind data supplied after actual LONG or LOB column" we are getting during data migration from source SQL server varbinary(max) to target oracle blob.

Answer (score 2):

Column orders are defined in the datastore under model, you need to get into related datastore and go to columns page, then you can use up and down arrows to arrange order.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the other answer, you can do it in the model section:

[image]